# Is it possible to define a PHP class server wide?

Tags: php

What I am asking is something like declaring environment variable in Apache for PHP like

```
SetEnv SITE_MAIN_DIR "/var/www/www.mydomain.com/"
```

That I can access anywhere in the site and it works great.

```
echo $_SERVER['SITE_MAIN_DIR']
```

Does PHP have similar to this for global classes so that I do not have to use include `/dir/class.php`;

`class::function($string);`
without using include?

Comment: You could set up an [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) if your class names can be mapped to a logical file/folder structure

Comment: No, an include of some kind is always required to include classes from PHP code. Autoloading can be used to automate the include when it's needed  and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) comes with an autoloader built-in. Only PHP built-ins can be used without first including them

Comment: Its ok, I was just curious, there are around 3000 functions in PHP and I wanted to add my own so that I don't have to use include'class.php' all the time and call the class directly. No biggie, just a thought came in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getenv()`

```
echo getenv(SITE_MAIN_DIR);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

But I would consider using an autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.4 has a new feature called [opcache preloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.preload), maybe this is what You are looking for.